# Blogger redirect after 5 seconds?

Tags: time, blogger

I would like to redirect a Blogger of me after 5 seconds but I found nothing regarding this.

Does someone maybe have a code or can write one for this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your head tag

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://yoururl.com"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting Blogger

sign in into your Blogger Account
Go to Blogger Dashboard -> choose settings -> Basics
Redirect your URL where you want to provide
and click redirect
it would take maximum of 10 minutes

if you are using Custom Domains Redirect using ghs. Google and conform your website domain name  this can be done through host providers like godaddy.com or add html tags for your website verification using Google web master tools.

it will take up to 30 minutes to redirect your site .

custom domain names may have paste ghs link from Blogger to the host provider example (www.godaddy.com)

Comment: Thanks, however, I mean a php redirect or something similar.